TimeoutError The driver failed to open the listening port 127.0.0.1:54901 whithin 10s
I am trying to open the edge browser with my VBA code, and I can't seem to make it work, the error I get is the one in the title: "TimeoutError The driver failed to open the listening port 127.0.0.1:54901 whithin 10s"
The version I have for edge according to the browser is 126.0.2592.87 (64 bits)

The driver version I installed is just the same (i picked the one that says x64, because that's the windows version I have) and I extracted the data from the zip inside the following path: "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic"

Selenium is also inside that.
I don't know what else to do.
Here's the code for reference:
Sub buscarPreco()

  Dim browser As New WebDriver

  browser.Start "edge", "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\SeleniumBasic\edgedriver.exe"
  browser.Get "/"
  browser.Wait 5000

  Cells(2, 2).Value = browser.FindElementById("price_inside_buybox").Attribute("innerText")

  Navegador.Quit

End Sub

